# Would police answer a girl's call based on her dream?

Tags: realism, the-black-phone

In the horror movie *The Black Phone*, Gwen keeps having dreams about her brother's abduction and finally she decides to call the detectives to inform them about the house she sees in her dream.

How realistic is this? Detectives would go to a location based on a girl's dream? Would not that be a less than convincing statement in their reports?

Answer (score 1):

In real life, it's not realistic at all. I doubt that police could legally search a house and have the resulting evidence hold up in court based on someone's dreams.

In-universe, prior to the call, the detectives have learned that Gwen has visions about evidence that they have not shared to the public, like The Grabber's black balloons. They even visit her at school and at her home (and her father at his work), to ask about how she knew of this information, but Gwen insisted that it's from her dreams.

> **Detective Miller:** You know what this is about.
> **Detective Wright:** What did you say to Amy about her brother Bruce?
> **Gwen:** Just that I had a dream about him.
> **Detective Wright:** What kind of a dream?
> **Gwen:** Just a weird one.
> **Detective Wright:** What happened in your dream?
> **Gwen:** He was taken. That's all.
> **Detective Wright:** By a man with black balloons in a van.
> **Gwen:** Yes.
> **Detective Wright:**: What else can you tell us about your dream?
> **Gwen:** Why? It was just a dream.
> **Detective Miller:** Who else knows about the dream?
> **Gwen:** Nobody.
> **Detective Wright:** We found two black balloons at the scene, Gwen.
> **Gwen:** Oh.
> **Detective Wright:** We also found one black balloon at the scene of Griffin Stagg's abduction.
> **Detective Miller:** And we never released those details, so...
> **Detective Wright:** So the question is, where did you hear about the balloons?
> **Gwen:** I didn't.
> **Detective Miller:** I'm gonna ask you again. How did you know about the balloons?
> **Detective Wright:** What aren't you telling us, Gwen?
> **Detective Miller:** Either there's a leak in the department, or...
> **Gwen:** Or what? I'm The Grabber?
> [...]
> **Detective Wright:** Gwen. What aren't you telling us?
> **Gwen:** That sometimes my dreams are right.

The detectives have probably come to the conclusion (or at least partially believe) that Gwen is actually a clairvoyant. So when she called, they believed her and immediately searched the house.

> Would not that be a less than convincing statement in their reports?

The detectives probably would've left out the part that they searched a house based on a girl's dream. There are other things they could've wrote in their report. The two detectives have already entered and have seen the inside of the house before, and have talked to Max (The Grabber's brother) inside. They could write that they searched the house based on what they saw inside or what Max said.